# While loop with database query gets slower on every cycle

Tags: php

I am struggling with a PHP script that generates a XLSX file of schools and teachers.
The goal is to generate 1 file with several sheets, each sheet is a school. On every sheet are the teachers information (name, last name, id, position)

I have 2 tables: 
Schools (id,school_number,school_name,level)
Teachers (id,school_number,name,last_name)

My php code is something like:

```
$level = $_GET['level'];
$Sql= "select * from schools where level = '".$level."' order by school_number";
$Query = $PDO->prepare($Sql);
if($Query->Execute()){

while($Schools = $Query->fetch()){
    $Sql = "select * from teachers where school_number = ".$Schools['school_number'];
    $Query2 = $PDO->prepare($Sql);
    if($Query2->Execute())  {
        WHILE($Teachers = $Query2->fetch())     {
            //GENERATE XLSX FILE WITH DATA
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is not my actual code, just for demo and you get a general idea of what it does without getting too deep into the rabbit-hole.

It will generate a file according to the school level, for example, one for elementary, other for high school, so on.

So, the problem I am having it's not necessarily of programming, **the code works** with most of the levels. It **makes the files and places the data correctly**.

However, when dealing with certain level (let's, say, elementary), that has way more schools than the others (around 400, 4 times over the others), the while loop gets way too slow and it doesn't generate the output file.

I've tried setting the max execution time two to four times it's original value, also ram. Didn't make a difference.

One weird thing: I added LIMIT 300 to the first query and it works ok. File it's created. Even at LIMIT 350, it does it too. When it gets over that number it starts to act weird.

Any ideas to solve the issue?

Comment: Any reason you think the issue is mysql / pdo related?

Comment: personally, i would not hold that initial query open and fetch rows interspersed with execution of other queries. if there's some requirement/need to do individual queries in a loop, then i would fetch the *entire* result from the initial query, store it in an array, and close that statement. be done with it. then loop through the entries in the array. i also wouldn't trust that the value of `school_number` is safe for inclusion in the SQL text. the pattern in the code is the pattern we see in code that is vulnerable to sql injection. use prepared statements with bind placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

There are two advantages of [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). First, user input is escaped to resolve any concerns of SQL injection. Second, the statement can be prepared once but executed multiple times to reduce overhead. You are avoiding both of these benefits.

Try something like this instead:

```
<?php
$level = $_GET['level'];
// we use a placeholder and pass the value to execute()
$sql = "SELECT school_number FROM schools WHERE level = ? ORDER BY school_number";
$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
if($stmt->execute([$level])) {
    $schools = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE school_number = ?";
    // note statement is prepared outside the loop
    $stmt2 = $PDO->prepare($sql);
    foreach($schools as $school) {
        if($stmt2->execute([$school["school_number"]])) {
            while ($teachers = $stmt2->fetch()) {
                //GENERATE XLSX FILE WITH DATA
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Though you could probably be doing this with a [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) instead:

```
<?php
$level = $_GET['level'];
$sql = "SELECT teachers.* FROM teachers LEFT JOIN schools USING (school_number) WHERE schools.level = ?";
$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
if($stmt->execute([$level])) {
    while ($teachers = $stmt->fetch()) {
        //GENERATE XLSX FILE WITH DATA
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Echoing Miken32's suggestion, use a `JOIN` to get data from both tables at once, and also `ORDER BY school_number`.  Then, as you loop through the combined table, remember (in a local variable) the latest `school_number` that you saw, so you can notice when the value changes ... when you have moved from one school to the next.  (If you do things "between schools," don't forget to do it one last time after the end of the loop ...)

The query now will take somewhat longer to execute *(of course you should have indexed the `teachers` table by `school_number` anyway ...),* but it will only execute once, and it will supply you with all the answers you need, all at once.

And, yes, use "prepared statements" when writing the new query:  only `level` will be a parameter in this case.

Needless to say, if you really intend to do this for "all levels," simply omit that test, `ORDER BY LEVEL, SCHOOL_NUMBER` and watch for changes in the values of both columns.  The database will happily hand you all the information you need in one go.